# When is the .this keyword unbound in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, bind

In what circumstance is the `.this` keyword unbound? In my react code, I have found that I have to use `this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this)` in the `constructor()` to access the properties of that method. Is this only when my method is triggered by an event listener, or is this necessary for all methods? Also are there any other situations that will break the access to `.this`?

Comment: Read [this](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/), starting from "ECMAScript 2015 classes".